# Find stochastic differential equation which best describes time-series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have a time series with daily observations in a time span of 20 years describing the price of commodities. Given that this time series is non-stationary, is it possible to find a Stochastic Differential Equation (SDE) from the type $dX = f(X)dt+g(X)dW$? If so, what would be an efficient algorithm or reference that I could use?

Comment: what is $W$ here?

Comment: @Dayne the Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly I would suggest three approaches to finding stochastic differential equations to test against your data. I do not have any substantial background knowledge in the pricing of commodities, so my advice is superficial in important aspects.

**Approach 1: First Principles Thinking**

Reading through the relevant literature you may come across principles that can be encoded into mathematical hypotheses in the form of stochastic differential equations. There may be entire families of differential equations compatible with a given qualitative principle, so be open-minded as you explore this.

**Approach 2: Historical Precedent**

Reading through the relevant literature on commodity pricing, you might come across existing models that you can test against your data.

**Approach 3: Data Driven Discovery**

Researchers have worked on the problem of trying to automatically discover the underlying governing equations of a system given a bounded space of possible models and available data. While they do not get into stochastic differential equations, I would advise you to look carefully at [Brunton et al 2016](https://www.pnas.org/content/113/15/3932) and potentially any studies connected to it in citation networks. You might try their approaches immediately as given, yielding best-fitting deterministic ODEs, or try to adapt their methods to your use case.